# Вывод даты добавления (например, 1 час назад)

Tags: дата, javascript, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Имеется timestamp в mysql, выводить его напрямую как-то некрасиво. Хочется выводить как, например, ВКонтакте: 1 час назад, 3 часа назад, вчера, 3 дня назад и так далее.

Может имеются готовые решения? Заранее большое спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function time($time) {
    $month_name = array(
        1 => 'января',
        2 => 'февраля',
        3 =>'марта',
        4 =>'апреля',
        5 =>'мая',
        6 =>'июня',
        7 =>'июля',
        8 =>'августа',
        9 =>'сентября',
        10 =>'октября',
        11 =>'ноября',
        12 =>'декабря'
    );

    $month = $month_name[date('n', $time)];
    $day = date('j', $time);
    $year = date('Y', $time);
    $hour = date('G', $time);
    $min = date('i', $time);
    $date = $day. ' '.$month. ' '.$year. ' г. в '.$hour. ':'.$min;
    $dif = time() - $time;

    if ($dif < 59) {
        return $dif. " сек. назад";
    } 
    elseif($dif / 60 > 1and $dif / 60 < 59) {
        return round($dif / 60). " мин. назад";
    } 
    elseif($dif / 3600 > 1and $dif / 3600 < 23) {
        return round($dif / 3600). " час. назад";
    }
    else{
        return $date;
    }
}
```

Comment: На вход какого формата строку подавать?

Comment: php - time(). Идеальный вариант для хранения в базе. Советую.

Comment: Круто, спасибо! :)

Answer (score 0):

или выводить из базы unix_timestamp(`date`) as `time` - тот же time() получается)